# about dollar sign: dollar sign within dollar sign?

Tags: variable

Suppose we have:

```
echo $A
abc

echo $B
def

echo $abcdef
yesyes
```

How do I get "yesyes" using A and B? I was trying something like:

```
${$A$B}        
$`echo "$A"$B`
```

but failed. Any advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Bash shell, then provided you introduce an intermediate variable you can use *indirection*:

```
$ echo $A
abc
$ echo $B
def
$ echo $abcdef
yesyes
```

then

```
$ AB=$A$B
$ echo "${!AB}"
yesyes
```

Variable indirection is described in the **Parameter Expansion* section of the Bash manual (`man bash`):

> ```
>    If the first character of parameter is an  exclamation  point  (!),  it
>    introduces a level of variable indirection.  Bash uses the value of the
>    variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable;
>    this  variable  is  then expanded and that value is used in the rest of
>    the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.   This  is
>    known as indirect expansion.  The exceptions to this are the expansions
>    of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below.  The exclamation  point
>    must  immediately  follow the left brace in order to introduce indirec‐
>    tion.
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know "exclamation mark" can be used this way. Can you help provide some more introduction of the use of ! in cases like this? a link or a manual will be great.

Comment: @user297997 I have added an extract from the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
$ eval "echo \$$(echo ${A}${B})"
yesyes
```

The above is of the general form, `eval "echo \$$(echo ...)`. The above converts the variables, `${A}${B}` into the string `abcdef`, and then eval's it as `echo \$abcdef`.

If you take the `eval` off you can see the intermediate form:

```
$ echo \$$(echo ${A}${B})
$abcdef
```

The `eval` is then expanding the variable, `$abcdef`.

#### References

- [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide - Chapter 28. Indirect References](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html)

Comment: worked perfectly!

Comment: What does the additional echo + command substitution do for you here (as opposed to `eval echo \$"$A$B"` for example)?

Comment: @steeldriver - nothing beyond showing ppl how to more mechanically put these things together. `eval "echo \$"${A}${B}""` works, but when I explain this to ppl at work etc, they're more confused by this, vs. the extra echo'ing, in my experience. It also allows for the pieces to be taken out and executed independently to see what's happening, IMO. But yours is more concise.